# Convert windows project with .dll files to linux

Tags: python, linux, dll, shared-libraries, jtag

I am trying to get a Python project to work on Linux. It already works under windows. Problematic are two .dll files that are used in the project.

It is this project: https://github.com/colinoflynn/pyjtagbs
In the folder /examples is a JLinkARM.dll. I have replaced this with a JLinkARM.so. I get the shared object file from the manufacturer website Segger JLink.

The other .dll is located at pyjtagbs/viveris/libjtagcore_x86.dll
This file is from another project written in C. Here is the link to the project https://github.com/viveris/jtag-boundary-scanner

Here I found a makefile under lib_jtag_core/build/linux
I executed this file under Linux and got a lot of .o files and a libjtag_core.so. I replaced the libjtagcore_x86.dll with libjtag_core.so and changed the name to lib_jtag_core.so (That is the filename jtagcore.py is looking for)

To sum up: I am running the pyjtagbs project under pycharm linux. I replaced the two .dll files in the way I described. When I now execute my example (what runs under windows) I get this error:

[OSError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zs5C.png)

I wonder why it looks for lib_jtag_core.so in examples folder. On Windows the .dll is not in the examples folder either.
Well, I copied lib_jtag_core.so to the examples folder and now I get this error message:
[exit code 139](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg0eb.png)

Does anyone have experience with transferring .dll data to the Linux system and can help me?
The problem is so specific, other posts on the forum could not help me. What exactly do I have to do to make my project run under Linux and to get all dependencies right?